# Unable to load tab in PagerSlidingTabStrip when fragment is replaced

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement a viewpager with a PagerSlidingTabStrip instead of a TabView. The viewpager has three tabs in which each listview displays a list of events. The three tabs are called Past, Tonight and Future.

I've set up the slider as the [github](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/README.md) page suggests:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_events_main_strip, container, false);     

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        pager = (ViewPager) v .findViewById(R.id.pager_main);
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        // Set Present tab as default
        pager.setCurrentItem(1);
        return v;
    }
```

When the app starts the Main Activity adds for the first time this fragment and everything works great. 3 swipeable tabs with 3 listviews. (c.f. code section)

**Here is the problem**:

I've noticed that when I press the back button and replace the fragment again, in order to reopen the viewpager, the tab in the middle doesn't show any listview. If I swype left or right the content in the other tabs is loaded and displayed but the Present Tab remains empty. 
When I debug the ToNightEvents ListFragment isn't called at all.
Do you guys have any suggestions to solve the problem?

**The code:**

The code is structured as follows: After the onCreateView I've added an OnDestroyView method to remove the fragment but it didn't work... Then in the fragmentPagerAdapter each page is called as a fragment in the getItem method. Finally at the end of the code you can see the three ListFragment classes in which a listview is populated through an AsyncTask

```
public class FragmentAllEvents extends Fragment 
{
    private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_LOGO = "logo";
    private static final String TAG_POKUID = "pokuid";

    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userListTotal;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    HashMap<String, String> userSelected;
    EventsFunctions eventsFunctions;
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    static ListView lv;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager pager;
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private Drawable oldBackground = null;
    private int currentColor = 0xFF666666;
    //Context context = this;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up the action bar.
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_events_main_strip, container, false);
        pager = (ViewPager) v .findViewById(R.id.pager_main);
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        pager.setCurrentItem(1);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() 
    {
         super.onDestroyView();
         getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
        {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) 
        {
            switch (i) 
            {
                case 0:
                    return new PastEvents();

                case 1:
                    return new ToNightEvents();

                case 2:
                    return new FutureEvents();

                /*default:
                    // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.

                    return new ToNightEvents();
                  */  
            }
            return null;
        }


        /**
         * A fragment that launches past events list.
         */
        public static class PastEvents extends ListFragment implements
        PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener 
        {
            private ListView pastList;
            private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;
            ProgressBar progress;
            String tabTime;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                View pastView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pastlist, container, false);
                progress = (ProgressBar) pastView.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner_past);
                tabTime="past";
                pastList = (ListView) pastView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                // Now get the PullToRefresh attacher from the Activity. An exercise to the reader
                // is to create an implicit interface instead of casting to the concrete Activity
                mPullToRefreshAttacher =  ((Home) getActivity()).getPullToRefreshAttacher();

                // Now set the ScrollView as the refreshable view, and the refresh listener (this)
                mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(pastList, this);

                new AsyncLoadEvents(getActivity(), progress, pastList, mPullToRefreshAttacher).execute(tabTime);
                return pastView;
            }


            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                super.onListItemClick (listView, view, position, id);
                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                //Log.e("AttendList Report", "Clicked list item: " + position +" Content: \n" + map.get(TAG_ID).toString());
                Log.e("PastList Report", "Clicked list item: " + position +" Event's content: \n" + map.get(TAG_UID).toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleEventActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("pokuid",map.get(TAG_POKUID)); // Maybe remove attribute toString();
                intent.putExtra("uid", map.get(TAG_UID)); 
                intent.putExtra("logo",map.get(TAG_LOGO));
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRefreshStarted(View view) 
            {
                new AsyncLoadEvents(getActivity(), progress, pastList, mPullToRefreshAttacher).execute(tabTime);                
            }

        }

        /**
         * A fragment that launches future event list.
         */
        public static class FutureEvents extends ListFragment  implements
        PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener 
        {
            private ListView futureList;
            private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;
            ProgressBar progress;
            String tabTime;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                View futureView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.futurelist, container, false);
                progress = (ProgressBar) futureView.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner_future);
                tabTime  = "future";
                futureList = (ListView) futureView.findViewById(android.R.id.list); //change to attendlist if needed


                // Now get the PullToRefresh attacher from the Activity. An exercise to the reader
                // is to create an implicit interface instead of casting to the concrete Activity
                mPullToRefreshAttacher =  ((Home) getActivity()).getPullToRefreshAttacher();

                // Now set the ScrollView as the refreshable view, and the refresh listener (this)
                mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(futureList, this);

                new AsyncLoadEvents(getActivity(), progress, futureList, mPullToRefreshAttacher).execute(tabTime);
                return futureView;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                super.onListItemClick (listView, view, position, id);

                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.e("PastList Report", "Clicked list item: " + position +" Event's content: \n" + map.get(TAG_UID).toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleEventActivity.class);


                intent.putExtra("pokuid",map.get(TAG_POKUID)); // Maybe remove attribute toString();
                intent.putExtra("uid", map.get(TAG_UID)); 
                intent.putExtra("logo",map.get(TAG_LOGO));
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onRefreshStarted(View view) 
            {
                new AsyncLoadEvents(getActivity(), progress, futureList, mPullToRefreshAttacher).execute(tabTime);              
            }
        }

        /**
         * A fragment that launches future event list.
         */
        public static class ToNightEvents extends ListFragment implements
        PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener 
        {
            private ListView tonightList;
            private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;
            ProgressBar progress;
            String tabTime;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                View tonightView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tonightlist, container, false);
                progress = (ProgressBar) tonightView.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner_tonight);
                tabTime  = "tonight";
                tonightList = (ListView) tonightView.findViewById(android.R.id.list); //change to attendlist if needed

                // Now get the PullToRefresh attacher from the Activity. An exercise to the reader
                // is to create an implicit interface instead of casting to the concrete Activity
                mPullToRefreshAttacher =  ((Home) getActivity()).getPullToRefreshAttacher();

                // Now set the ScrollView as the refreshable view, and the refresh listener (this)
                mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(tonightList, this);

                new AsyncLoadEvents(getActivity(), progress, tonightList, mPullToRefreshAttacher).execute(tabTime);
                return tonightView;
            }


            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                super.onListItemClick (listView, view, position, id);

                HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.e("PastList Report", "Clicked list item: " + position +" Event's content: \n" + map.get(TAG_UID).toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleEventActivity.class);


                intent.putExtra("pokuid",map.get(TAG_POKUID)); // Maybe remove attribute toString();
                intent.putExtra("uid", map.get(TAG_UID)); 
                intent.putExtra("logo",map.get(TAG_LOGO));
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onRefreshStarted(View view) 
            {
                new AsyncLoadEvents(getActivity(), progress, tonightList, mPullToRefreshAttacher).execute(tabTime);             
            }
        }

        public String[] titles=
        {
            "Past",
            "Tonight",
            "Future"
        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
        {
            return titles[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: I am also having same problem please update ???

Comment: @SparX Did you solve the problem please update

Comment: @AZ_ I did it differently. I have two fragments now: Main and Front Fragment. Main contains PSTS. I just replace front fragment and put other fragments on front.

Answer (score 5):

This would normally work if you were in an Activity, however I guess you are in a Fragment since the code you posted is the method onCreateView(). The problem is that you are trying to use the FragmentManager of the Activity and you should be using the Fragment's FragmentManager. This FragmentManager is not what you need. Try this instead:

```
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

I think I'm a little bit late but if anyone happens to have the same error here is the solution =)

Q.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed it for me:

- Add an OnBackStackChangedListener to the fragment manager.
- In the onBackStackChanged method, get references to both the ViewPager and the PagerSlidingTabStrip (pager and tabs in your example). If the appropriate fragment is currently active, do the following:

  ```
  pager.invalidate();
  tabs.invalidate();
  pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
  tabs.setViewPager(pager);
  ```